# Adding to Map in MongoDB Java

Tags: java, database, mongodb, dictionary

I have a Map stored in MongoDB. I also have this map in my Java program as a local cache HashMap. Currently, I update the local cache as necessary, and then override the map with my changes:

```
HashMap<String, String> myHashMap; // For Reference
myHashMap.put("example", "value");

Bson update = Updates.set("my_map", myHashMap);
myCollection.updateOne(Filters.eq("id", id), update, DataManager.UPSERT);
```

This works fine, but I am worried that this will be a bad idea when this hashmap eventually reaches thousands or maybe even millions of entries. This code is running every few minutes on many different accounts connected to the same MongoDB server, and I worry setting the entire HashMap every single time will cause performance issues, as it attempts to rewrite thousands of entries that are already there.

Is there a way to simply add a single entry into a map in my MongoDB document? Or maybe I am misunderstanding how Updates.Set works and it shouldn't be an issue with a massive map? Thanks!